# how to INSERT item in drop down list at the index other than 0 to "n"?

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I want to insert an item in drop down list at an index other than 0. I've bound my drop down datavaluefield with identity starting from 1 and want to insert an item on selected value other than 0 to "n", n being any number. Can I get some help? 
here's my code:

```
public void Bind_ddlSelectGroup()
    {
        using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select g.GroupId, g.GroupName from timeOtime.dbo.[Group] as g where IsDeleted=0", Database.con))
        {
            using(SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                sda.Fill(ds);
                ddlSelectGroup.DataSource = null;
                ddlSelectGroup.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                ddlSelectGroup.DataTextField = "GroupName";
                ddlSelectGroup.DataValueField = "GroupId";
                ddlSelectGroup.DataBind();
            }
        }
        ddlSelectGroup.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select All Groups--", "0"));

    }
```

I want to insert an item as "--Ungrouped--" in dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I added the required item("--Ungrouped--") at the bottom of dropdownlist.

```
ddlSelectGroup.Items.Insert(ddlSelectGroup.Items.Count, new ListItem("--Ungrouped--", "ungrouped"));
```

it worked fine.